# My Discord Bot will not respond to any commands when I add an 'on_message'-client event

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots, client

As the title suggests I'm having difficulties with my Discord Bot. I have 2 client events and a couple more commands, those are, for overview, not included in the code down below. When I comment out the 'on_message'-event all the commands function properly but as soon as I uncomment it, neither the 'on_message' nor the commands work and there is no error message in the console either so I'm clueless as to what I am doing wrong here.

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', help_command=None)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    channel = client.get_channel(821133655081484318)
    print(f'Welcome, {client.user.name} is up and running!')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    with open("author.json", "r") as f:
        author_dic = json.load(f)
    if message.author.bot or message.content.startswith("!"):
        return None 
    try:
        for list in author_dic.values():
            for el in list:
                if str(message.author) == el:
                    channelobj = client.get_channel(list[1])
                    if message.channel != channelobj:
                        await channelobj.send(message.content)
    except IndexError:
        return None

@client.command()
async def getid(ctx, given_name=None):
    ...

client.run("TOKEN")
```

I'd be really glad to have someone help me out since I'm kind of lost, already thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `await client.process_commands(message)` ([check this issue in documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working)).

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # rest of your on_message code

    await client.process_commands(message) # add this line at the end of your on_message event
```